# React Typescript - How add Types to location.state when passed in a Route

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router

I am getting an error when I pass react-router props sent to a component in a Route because I have specific state that I pass this component but the error shows up in my Route.

[image]

Here is the Route code:

```
<Route
    exact
    path='/flipltimeline'
    render={props => <FliplTimeline {...props} />
```

In another component I call this below

```
props.history.push(`/flipltimeline`, {
      Approval: singleFliplApprovals,
      InvestigationID,
      Unit: unit,
      Cost: cost
    });
```

Here is the code for the Component. I finally got Typescript to compile this but I had to merge LocationState & TimelineState to get this to work. But now Typescript throws the above screenshot when I send props to my FliplTimeline component. Anyone have and idea how to fix this?

history.tsx

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';

let baseNameProd = '';

if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
  console.log('Looks like we are in development mode!');
  baseNameProd = '';
} else {
  baseNameProd = '/flipl';
}

const customHistory = createBrowserHistory({
  basename: baseNameProd
});

export default customHistory;
```

FliplTimeline.tsx

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { History, LocationState } from 'history';

interface FliplTimelineLocationState {
  Approval: any;
  InvestigationID: number;
  Unit: string;
  Cost: number;
}

interface TimelineState{
  state: FliplTimelineLocationState;
}

interface Props {
  history: History;
  location: LocationState & TimelineState;
}

function FliplTimeline(props: Props) {
  return (
    <ModuleTemplate title='Status Timeline' subtitle=''>
      <FliplTimelineJumbotron className='bg-primary-darker shadow-4 line-height-serif-4'>
        <div className='grid-row'>
          <div className='grid-col-4'>
            <span
              className='font-mono-2xl text-white'
              style={{
                verticalAlign: 'middle'
              }}
            >
              FLIPL{' '}
            </span>
            <span
              className='font-mono-xl text-gold'
              style={{
                verticalAlign: 'middle'
              }}
            >
              {props.location.state.InvestigationID}
            </span>
```

Update: Added my history.tsx file in which I created my own history for React-Router. Also added in the import statements.

Update: Tried to change my FliplTimeline component to have this interface

```
import { RouteComponentProps } from 'react-router-dom'

function FliplTimeline(props: RouteComponentProps ) {
```

I get 2 errors. First one is this one and another that says that the shape of the props are wrong. Ideas?
[image: tserror]

Update: I was able to finally get the right props declaration for my component.

```
import { RouteComponentProps } from 'react-router-dom';

interface FliplTimelineLocationState {
  Approval: any;
  InvestigationID: number;
  Unit: string;
  Cost: number;
}

function FliplTimeline(
  props: RouteComponentProps<{}, any, FliplTimelineLocationState | any>
)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was able to get it working.

```
import { RouteComponentProps } from 'react-router-dom';

interface FliplTimelineLocationState {
  Approval: any;
  InvestigationID: number;
  Unit: string;
  Cost: number;
}

function FliplTimeline(
  props: RouteComponentProps<{}, any, FliplTimelineLocationState | any>
)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `RouteComponentProps` and feed it the appropriate types for its generic.  This article covers quite a bit: [How to Use React Router in Typescript](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/react-router-typescript).

Using React Router with TypeScript almost necessitates filling in the generics that React Router has.  Otherwise there isn't enough context to determine the types of everything.  Compare to my example below.  I use `useHistory` and fill it with the type that I want to be made available.  This would probably be your `FliplTimelineLocationState` that way the `state` property of `history` would be determinable to be of type `FliplTimelineLocationState`.

```
import React, {MouseEventHandler} from "react";
import {Route, RouteComponentProps, StaticContext, useHistory} from "react-router";
import {BrowserRouter, Link} from "react-router-dom";

interface IMyScreenRouteParams {
    foo: string;
}

// You don't have to extend, you could just use StaticContext
interface IMyStaticContext extends StaticContext {
    bar: string;
}

interface IHistory {
    fizz: string;
}

const Nav = () => {
    const history = useHistory<IHistory>();

    const clickHanlder: MouseEventHandler = () => {
        history.push("/my-screen", {
            fizz: "you said fizz"
        });
    };

    return (
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><Link to="/">Home</Link></li>
                <li><Link to="/my-screen">My Screen</Link></li>
                <li><button onClick={clickHanlder}>My Screen with state</button></li>
                <li><Link to="/my-screen?q=hello">My Screen with query</Link></li>
                <li><Link to="/my-screen/bob">My Screen using match</Link></li>
            </ul>
            <div>
                <button onClick={() => history.goBack()}>Back</button>
                <button onClick={() => history.push("/")}>Home</button>
                <button onClick={() => history.goForward()}>Forward</button>
            </div>
        </nav>
    );
};

const MyScreen = ({
    location,
    match,
    history,
    staticContext
}: RouteComponentProps<IMyScreenRouteParams, IMyStaticContext, IHistory>) => (
    <div>
        <section>
            <h2>Location</h2>
            <p><code>location</code> has <code>IHistory</code> props.</p>
            <pre><code>{JSON.stringify(location, null, 4)}</code></pre>
        </section>
        <section>
            <h2>Match</h2>
            <p><code>match</code> has <code>IMyScreenRouteParams</code> props.</p>
            <pre><code>{JSON.stringify(match, null, 4)}</code></pre>
        </section>
        <section>
            <h2>History</h2>
            <p><code>history</code> has <code>IHistory</code> props.</p>
            <pre><code>{JSON.stringify(history, null, 4)}</code></pre>
        </section>
        <section>
            <h2>Static Context</h2>
            <p><code>staticContext</code> has <code>IMyStaticContext</code> props or whatever static context your router has.</p>
            <p>This is for a <a href="https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/StaticRouter/context-object"><code>&lt;StaticRouter/&gt;</code></a>.</p>
            <pre><code>{JSON.stringify(staticContext, null, 4)}</code></pre>
        </section>
    </div>
);

const Router = () => (
    <BrowserRouter>
        <div
            style={{
                display: "flex",
                flexDirection: "row"
            }}
        >
            <Nav />
            <main>
                <Route exact path="/" component={() => (<div>Click something in the <code>&lt;nav/&gt;</code></div>)} />
                <Route exact path="/my-screen" component={MyScreen} />
                <Route exact path="/my-screen/:id" component={MyScreen} />
            </main>
        </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
);

export default Router;
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I am using a class component in this and I know there is a difference using hooks in this example. I will try to use the RouteComponentProps.