# How to use react-router Link to access props.location in React typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-router-dom, react-router-v4

I tried the way it is described here [React Typescript - How add Types to location.state when passed in a Route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60343598/react-typescript-how-add-types-to-location-state-when-passed-in-a-route) but its not working for me. I want to be able to access the page number whenever the user is coming from User.js.

User.js

```
<Link to={{ pathname: "/List", state: { page: '4' }}}> Click Here </Link>
```

List.js

```
interface Props {
  filter1: string; 
  filter2: string;
  location ?: RouteComponentProps<{ location: string }, {}, { state: string }>;
}

export default function List ({filter1, filter2, location}: Props) {
  console.log(location); //Shows undefined
}
```

filter1 and filter2 will be passed as props from another component and they have nothing to do with User.js

Comment: can you explain how I am supposed to define the routes?  I’ll be using useLocation in case this doesn’t work out though.

Comment: Just trying the withRouter HOC you suggested. The routes are already defined in the first way so that wouldn't be the problem

Comment: Also, is it okay to set the required data in localstorage and delete it as soon as i access it from my settings page?

Comment: I'll just be storing a simple number so I believe security won't be any issue? But frequent read write from localStorage definitely bugs me

Comment: Cool. So localStorage is definitely one way to handle this. But what would be the preferred way to pass a simple number between sibling components?

Answer (score 2):

If `location` is not available to you in `props`, that means you have defined Routes a little differently i.e. *not* passed the [Route Props](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/route-props) to your component.

To pass those props, you can [define your routes](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/route-render-methods) like:

```
<Route path="/some-path" component={SomeComponent}/>
```

Or

```
<Route path="/some-path" render={props => <SomeComponent {...props} />}/>
```

If you define routes like:

```
<Route path="/some-path">
  <SomeComponent />
</Route>
```

route props (`history`, `location`, `match`) will not be passed to your component. But that doesn't mean it is an incorrect way to define Route. It is actually the preferred way to define routes. Because we can use hooks like [useHistory](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/usehistory), [useLocation](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/uselocation) [etc.](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks) to get history and location in our function components.

Comment: And, there is an HOC [withRouter](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/withRouter) which you can use in Class Components (and functions as well) to make the Route-Props available to your component in its props.